# Display associated taxonomy child name on single CPT page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I have a custom post type called products.

I've created a hierarchical taxonomy called archive categories.
Within this taxonomy I've created top level and sub categories (image below)

[image]

What I would like to do is when viewing the single post page is to display the names of a selected sub category (date).

Ulitmately I want to display the CPT taxonomy name like:
**Date:** 2001

I've looked into and tried [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) and [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) but these results return all taxonomies, not ones associated with the post.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To return the list of terms attached to that post, try `get_the_term_list()`.  This will return the terms for a single post and by using the before, separator and after arguments you can easily build an HTML markup structure to suit your needs.

The following example creates an unordered list of terms from the Topics taxonomy attached to a specific post:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'topics', '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' );
if ( $terms ): ?>
  <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Topics:', 'yourtextdomain' ); ?></h2>
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $terms, 'yourtextdomain' );
endif;
```

WP Codex entry for `tget_the_term_list()`:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list